# How do I optimize this MYSQL JOIN Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I am having a hard time dealing with query optimization and I believe the one am currently using can be improved a lot.

I have 4 tables;

```
Artist (14,930 rows)
```

| artist_id | artist_name | artist_slug | artist_country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elle | elle | 5 |

```
Country (85 rows)
```

| country_id | country_name | country_slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | usa |

```
Song (61,119 rows)
```

| song_id | song_title | song_artist_id | song_plays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kitty kat | 1 | 38291 |
| 2 | Donkey | 1 | 8291 |

```
Lyrics (61,119 rows)
```

| lyrics_id | lyrics_song_id | lyrics_body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Kitty Kat lyrics |
| 2 | 2 | Donkey lyrics |

Am joining the tables using this query fetching a single artist's data plus, country, the total number of songs, the sum of the plays on all songs by the artist, and the total number of lyrics.

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(2000) */ 
artist.*,
country.*,
COUNT(song.song_id) AS TotalSongs,
COUNT(lyrics.lyrics_id) AS TotalLyrics,
SUM(song.song_plays) AS TotalPlays
FROM artist
LEFT JOIN country ON artist.artist_country_id = country.country_id
LEFT JOIN song ON artist.artist_id = song.song_artist_id
LEFT JOIN lyrics ON song.song_id = lyrics.lyrics_song_id 
WHERE artist_status = 'enabled' AND artist.artist_slug = '$slug'
GROUP BY artist.artist_id LIMIT 0, 1
```

How do I improve it to execute faster and use less resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know you can change the SQL much. I do worry the multiple joins are **multiplying** your `COUNT()` results, where you might find you need correlated subqueries in the `SELECT` clause instead for some of those counts. That's likely to make things _slower_, but it could also be necessary if you want accurate results. For performance here, I'd start with your indexing.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Consider merging `Song` and `Lyrics` into a single table.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, the `LIMIT 1` returns an unpredictable row.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can determine what indexes are missing.

Comment: Do you need both the country_name and slug?

Comment: What table is ``artist_status` in?  If in `artists`, then a composite index may make a big improvement.

Comment: @RickJames yes. say for countries like United States of America, the slug would just be USA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use a subquery in select clause for aggregation:

```
SELECT artist.*, country.*, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM song
    WHERE song.song_artist_id = artist.artist_id
) AS total_songs, (
    SELECT SUM(song_plays)
    FROM song
    WHERE song.song_artist_id = artist.artist_id
) AS total_plays, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM song
    JOIN lyrics ON song.song_id = lyrics.lyrics_song_id
    WHERE song.song_artist_id = artist.artist_id
) AS total_lyrics
FROM artist
LEFT JOIN country ON artist.artist_country_id = country.country_id
WHERE artist_status = 'enabled'
AND artist.artist_slug = :slug
```

In MySQL 8 or later you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT artist.*, country.*, lj.*
FROM (artist LEFT JOIN country ON artist.artist_country_id = country.country_id), LATERAL (
    SELECT COUNT(song.song_id) total_songs, SUM(song_plays) total_plays, COUNT(lyrics.lyrics_id) total_lyrics
    FROM song
    LEFT JOIN lyrics ON song.song_id = lyrics.lyrics_song_id
    WHERE song.song_artist_id = artist.artist_id
) AS lj
WHERE artist_status = 'enabled'
AND artist.artist_slug = :slug
```

Comment: @Busker -- How much faster is this formulation?

Answer (score 0):

Create all the indexes on the tables with columns as :

```
CREATE INDEX index_name1 ON artist (artist_country_id ); 
CREATE INDEX index_name2 ON country (country_id); 
CREATE INDEX index_name3 ON artist (artist_id ); 
CREATE INDEX index_name4 ON song (song_artist_id); 
CREATE INDEX index_name5 ON artist (artist_status );
```

and create a view as such:

```
CREATE VIEW customerPayments
AS 
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(2000) */ 
artist.*,
country.*,
COUNT(song.song_id) AS TotalSongs,
COUNT(lyrics.lyrics_id) AS TotalLyrics,
SUM(song.song_plays) AS TotalPlays
FROM artist
LEFT JOIN country ON artist.artist_country_id = country.country_id
LEFT JOIN song ON artist.artist_id = song.song_artist_id
LEFT JOIN lyrics ON song.song_id = lyrics.lyrics_song_id 
WHERE artist_status = 'enabled' AND artist.artist_slug = '$slug'
GROUP BY artist.artist_id LIMIT 0, 1;
```

A view is a named query stored in the database catalog

**View does not physically store the data.** When you issue the SELECT statement against the view, MySQL executes the underlying query specified in the view’s definition and returns the result set. For this reason, sometimes, **a view is referred to as a virtual table.**

A Materialized View (MV) is the pre-calculated (materialized) result of a query. **Unlike a simple VIEW the result of a Materialized View is stored somewhere, generally in a table**. Materialized Views are used when immediate response is needed and the query where the Materialized View bases on would take to long to produce a result. Materialized Views have to be refreshed once in a while. It depends on the requirements how often a Materialized View is refreshed and how actual its content is. Basically a Materialized View can be refreshed immediately or deferred, it can be refreshed fully or to a certain point in time. MySQL does not provide Materialized Views by itself. But it is easy to build Materialized Views yourself.

**As materialzed views gets data on the basis of cache they are faster than views.**
There is no concept of materialized views in Mysql.But you can implement your own materialized views by https://fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: Since it is tagged [mysql], please note that "Materialized Views" do not exist in MySQL.  More to the point MySQL's Views are just syntactic sugar, and sometimes even run slower than the equivalent Select.